# Unable to install mongoose on windows 10

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
PS E:\Selvam\Prepare Myself\NodeJs\module3\start> npm install mongoose --save
-
> kerberos@0.0.15 install E:\Selvam\Prepare Myself\NodeJs\module3\start\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)


E:\Selvam\Prepare Myself\NodeJs\module3\start\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or
PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [E:\Selvam\Prepare Myself\NodeJs\module3\start\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerbe
ros\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [E:\Selvam\Prepare Myself\NodeJs\module3\start\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_
modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Selvam\Prepare Myself\NodeJs\module3\start\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
mongoose@4.1.10 node_modules\mongoose
├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
├── async@0.9.0
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── muri@1.0.0
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── ms@0.1.0
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── bson@0.4.16
├── mquery@1.6.3 (bluebird@2.9.26)
└── mongodb@2.0.42 (es6-promise@2.1.1, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.2.10)
```

Comment: please try at least to elaborate a bit on what you want to do and what happened. just puking your stack trace into the question won't cause anyone to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error. After installing VS Community 2015, I had to open VS and create an JavaScript Project. VS asked me to install further packages. After Installing the error was solved.

Comment: More specifically it requires the "common tools for visual c++" which comes with the cordova installation if you want to create a javascript project.

Answer (score 1):

`Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.`

`error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe".`

```
TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [E:\Selvam\Prepare Myself\NodeJs\module3\start\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerbe
ros\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
```

You either don't have Visual Studio installed, your installation is corrupt or your TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset is set to an invalid version number.

Comment: thanks! for giving your valuable time..let me check my visual studio installation

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
download and install Python 2.7.11
add C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts to PATH in Environment Variables, remember to separate paths with a semicolon
npm install -g cordova
npm install mongoose
```